# How to show UIImage background through transparent pixels of image

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have an image, that has transparent areas and a known backround. But wheh I set "image" property of the UIImage i see main view and not a color which i set in "background" property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to create custom control with two UIImageViews bounded by obu UIView. It works, but i would prefer apple doing something about this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I think I tried that before and found no real solution. You could however put the uiimageview into an uiview with the same size and set the backgroundcolor to this view.

Comment: Well... Had to create custom control with two UIImageViews bounded by obu UIView. I works, but i would prefer apple doing something about this behaviour :( Thanks anyway.